# How to merge VB.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to combine VB.NET and C# languages in one application.

How can I use these two languages in one application? 
I haven't tried anything before because I have no idea about combining.

Comment: There are plenty of questions like *"call vb from c#"*. Need more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create two separate assemblies; you can't have C# and VB.NET in the same assembly.  Period.

If you have one assembly -- say, an executable -- written in one language, you can then reference the other assembly -- which is written in the other language -- all in one happy (but confused) application.

Comment: But it's possible right? @roryap

Comment: Is that a real question?  Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did @roryap

Comment: As hilarious as this comment thread is, you actually *can* do it by using the two different compilers to build modules, and then linking them together to create a multi-module assembly. But I have no idea why someone would want to do that. Just create two different assemblies and reference them. Far simpler.